# Внутренние уведомления laravel

Tags: laravel

Как сделать внутренние уведомления на сайте? чтобы при выполнении функции отправлялось уведомление целевому пользователю? уведомление будет отображаться в шапке страницы. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не смог найти подобных примеров, https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/notifications не подходит, либо я не правильно понял

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело ведь не в Laravel. Смотрите, опишу один из способов доставки таких уведомлений:

1. Создаете связующую таблицу в БД

---

```
column          | type
-----------------------------
id              | bigserial
user_id         | biginteger
notification_id | biginteger
```

---

2. При вызове функции делаете запись в эту таблицу данные
3. При загрузке страницы выбираете данные, используя эту таблицу и выводите уведомление.
4. Если пользователь сидит сейчас на сайте есть несколько вариантов:

   - по таймауте Javascript'ом дергать данные из этой таблицы и обновлять view;
   - прикрутить websocket'ы ([Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) - PHP или [Socket IO](https://socket.io/) - Node JS или любые другие сокеты) и при вызове этого метода писать в сокет это событие и обновлять данные.

Comment: 4. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting